# which read or scan function to be used to quickly store a dump of parameters from excel

Tags: r, regex, strsplit, read.csv

I have an excel file, an extract of which looks like this, after reading it using a plain `read.csv(filename)`. Have copy-pasted first 16 lines of one column of the imported data.

```
 [1] UserName, UserPassword, AppVersion, UserId, UUID, AppId, Latitude, Longitude        
 [2] UserId, UUID                                                                        
 [3] UserId, UUID                                                                        
 [4] UserId, UUID                                                                        
 [5] UserId, UUID                                                                        
 [6] UserId, UUID                                                                        
 [7] SessionId, StatusId, UserId, UUID                                                   
 [8] RoomId, Rows, Columns, SeatsRemoved, UserId, UUID                                   
 [9] SessionId, UserId, UUID                                                             
[10] QueryId, UserId, UUID                                                               
[11] SessionId, SeatIdList, StudentIdList, StatusId, UserId, UUID                        
[12] RoomId, UserId, UUID                                                                
[13] SessionId, UserId, UUID                                                             
[14] SessionId, UserId, UUID                                                             
[15] SessionId, UserId, UUID                                                             
[16] MessageType, MessageContent, SenderId, ReceiverId
```

Note: I used `noquote()` to strip the quotes out.

What I need is to pull in all parameter values (which are comma-separated single words in the list above) into one vector (char vector). I need a clean and elegant way to do this. I know of messy ways by using the function `str_split` which messes with the data badly. See below.

`str_split(y,",")`

```
[[1]] [1] "UserName"      " UserPassword" " AppVersion"   " UserId"    " UUID"         " AppId"        [7] " Latitude"     " Longitude"   

[[2]] [1] "UserId" " UUID" 

[[3]] [1] "UserId" " UUID" 

[[4]] [1] "UserId" " UUID" 

[[5]] [1] "UserId" " UUID" 

[[6]] [1] "UserId" " UUID" 

[[7]] [1] "SessionId" " StatusId" " UserId"   " UUID"    

[[8]] [1] "RoomId"        " Rows"         " Columns"      " SeatsRemoved" " UserId"       " UUID"
```

.....

All words are needed in one neat character vector. I am sure there is a straightforward way to do this. Appreciate if you can just provide me with a hint.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand correctly. The final structure you are looking for would be equivalent to `c( "UserName", " UserPassword", " AppVersion", ...)`

Comment: Yes exactly! @IanWesley

Comment: Please let me know if that is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
unlist(strsplit(y,","))
```

Comment: Actually, the second one did the trick. Only i have to run it twice for the two columns.
`unlist(strsplit(data$V1,","))` and
`unlist(strsplit(data$V2,","))` 
I was missing the **unlist** bit.
Thanks.

Comment: you may remove the first section and I will accept the answer.